# Cheerio how to ignore elements of a certain tag

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am scraping the body of the webpage:

```
axios.get(url)
.then(function(response){
        var $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        var body = $('body').text();
    });
```

The problem is, I want to exclude contents from the `<footer>` tag. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

cheerio creates a pseudo-DOM when it parses the HTML.  You can manipulate that DOM similar to how you would manipulate the DOM in a browser.  In your specific case, you could remove items from the DOM using any number of methods such as

```
 .remove()
 .replaceWith()
 .empty()
 .html()
```

So, the basic idea is that you would use a selector to find the footer element and then remove it as in:

```
$('footer').remove();
```

Then, fetch the text after you've removed those elements:

```
var body = $('body').text();
```